# Multi-Tee Cluster Lights

Tags: led, wiring

I have a set of `Lumineo 1512 Multi-Colored Clustered lights`.  At any given point on the line there may be between 2 and 5 wires.

[image: Cluster Lights]

## My Goal

I want a level of my tree to have multiple Junctions, one for each Branch, and just go OUT from the base, and terminate at the end of the branch.  Thus, not having to loop back inward.  Then a final junction going up to the next level to again multi-junction for that level.

My main question is for advice on:

1. How to split one electrical path into multiple paths to begin with.
2. How to mitigate splicing/splitting a variable number of wires for each junction with as little waste as possible.

I hope this isn't the case, but I'm not sure if a more experienced person would tell me a splicing method that may require adding resistors or (hopefully not) modifying the control box.  I'll solder if I have to, but it isn't my day job.

My experience: I was an Electronics Tech in the Navy, and have been an IT for a long time, part of which has included some component level repair and soldering.  I'm no pro at anything, let alone these odd 5-wire lights.  Any pointing to documentation or methods is appreciated.

Comment: how are these lights powered?

Comment: Plain US 110 wall outlet

Comment: I don't understand. Won't a plain old multi-tap extension cord do the trick? What haven't you told us?

Comment: I currently do things the easy way.  I am looking to run about 10-20 inches of wire from the trunk to the end of a branch and terminate, not loop back toward the trunk and doubl'ing up the lights on each branch